# How do I draw a circle UIView that acts like one with UICollisionBehavior?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicollisionbehavior

In my app, I'm currently drawing a basic view, and then I'm trying to round it's corners using a CAShapeLayer, but the UICollisionBehavior still reacts like it's a square that is drawn.

Here's an example of my code

```
  UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds
                                           byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners
                                                 cornerRadii:radiiSize];

// Mask the container view’s layer to round the corners.
CAShapeLayer *cornerMaskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[cornerMaskLayer setPath:path.CGPath];
self.containerView.layer.mask = cornerMaskLayer;
self.containerView.layer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing = YES;
```

Comment: It looks like UIKit Dynamics is limited to rectangular shapes. A core design decision was to be low overhead, so it's a pretty simplistic engine.

Comment: Hopefully iOS 8 brings this feature to the engine.

Answer (score -3):

Just do this rather than use UIBezierPath

```
self.containerView.layer.cornerRadius = [Radius is half the height/width];
self.containerView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: I've tried this, still behaves like a square. So weird. I don't want to try and hack in Sprite Kit.

Comment: I have used it in ImageView and it works there. I am trying it on normal UIView right now.

Comment: Could you show me the snippet of your code that gets this to work? Would be extremely grateful.

Comment: Just those two lines on your viewDidLoad. I have tested it.

Comment: Still won't work for some reason. Do you have a github where you could host a quick project?

Comment: I have. But you can just create one view, then set layer cornerRadius. Then set clipsToBounds. It will work. Just try to replace your code with the code above.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I have no idea what I could be doing wrong.

Comment: Do you have a link of your source code somewhere so that I can have a look? Or you can send the source code to ethan.fang@hotmail.com and I will fix it for you.